# Security View in WSUS on Server 2016 shows Language Packs?

Tags: wsus, windows-server-2016

I'm in the process of replacing my existing WSUS server with a new one running Windows Server 2016, and almost immediately I noticed something weird. Language packs are all showing up under my Security Updates view. See:

[image: Screenshot of WSUS Security Updates view]

Is this expected behavior? Is there a way to fix this? I cannot get them to go away, even after unchecking the Windows 10 language packs and re-syncing. I do have users in several countries, and while English speaking, some of them prefer their native language (German, French, etc), so I initially checked the box for them under Products & Classifications for Windows 10. I did not have Language Packs checked on the old server, so I am not sure if it's always behaved this way.

**I creating a New View w/ only 1 rule, Classification "Security Updates" and that view behaves as expected - it is only the built in view**. While I could just live with using my "Security-FIXED" view, it doesn't sit right with me that it's showing those as security updates. If it behaved the same way in my manual view, then I'd buy that they are potentially classified as "Security Updates", but since they do not show up with the only filter being classification, then something isn't quite right here. I may rebuild w/o selecting language packs if I can't find a solution, since this server isn't yet in production. I'm not looking forward to a second 400GB update download though from initial approval.